# Add attribute to react native components during input text change

Tags: react-native, native-base

Is there a way to add attributes to a React component during text change ?

I've a registration page, i would like to highlight the text box by adding "error" attribute to  components.

PS: I'm using NativeBase for my project, the "Input" is equals to "Text" in react native.

Below is the code without error

```
<Item>
  <Input placeholder='Email' onChangeText={(val) => this.validateEmail(val)}/>
  <Icon name='close-circle' />
</Item>
```

Below is the code will show error

```
  <Item error>
    <Input placeholder='Email' onChangeText={(val) => this.validateEmail(val)}/>
    <Icon name='close-circle' />
  </Item>
```

[image]

If adding extra attribute during action is not possible, could you all please suggest me a way to achieve this ?

Sorry for the question i'm still very new to react native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set error to true or false based on state and have validateEmail toggle that state value:

```
this.state = {
  showError: false
}
...
<Item error={this.state.showError}>

and somewhere inside validateEmail you would do this.setState({ showError: true })
```